# NewCustomForm.aspx in a List is not working in SharePoint 2013 after migrating from SharePoint 2010

Tags: migration, upgrade

NewCustomForm.aspx in a List is not working in SharePoint 2013 after migrating from SharePoint 2010.

The textbox, textarea & listbox controls are not visible in NewCustomForm.aspx in a List in SharePoint 2013 after migrating from SharePoint 2010. However the NewCustomForm.aspx  in a List works as expected in SharePoint 2010.

Kindly suggest solution to above problem ASAP.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any customization you made on these pages? Is there any custom master page you used on old farm? If you create a list, are these columns viewable? Did you check to select them from "modify this view" option?

Comment: [Check this Link Once](http://www.daoudisamir.com/fix-broken-sharepoint-lists/)